# Android Color Interpolation

Tags: android, listview, interpolation

I want to change textcolor of a textview which is in the header of the listview from a particular color (This could be any color) to WHITE onscroll of the listview.

I read about HSV and I need to decrease values of H and S towards 0 and increase the value of V towards 1 to get a color closer to WHITE

Has someone done a similar thing where in interpolation would happen with the value of scrollY?

Comment: use `setOnScrollListener(AbsListView.OnScrollListener)` and `android.animation.ArgbEvaluator`

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help:

```
private final float[] mHsvTemp = new float[3];

int hsvInterplate(float[] hsvWhen0, float[] hsvWhen1, float scale) {
    if (scale <= 0) return Color.HSVToColor(hsvWhen0);
    if (scale >= 1) return Color.HSVToColor(hsvWhen1);
    float hDist = hsvWhen1[0] - hsvWhen0[0];
    if (hDist > 180) hDist -= 360;
    else if (hDist <= -180) hDist += 360;
    mHsvTemp[0] = hsvWhen0[0] + hDist * scale;
    mHsvTemp[1] = hsvWhen0[1] + (hsvWhen0[1] - hsvWhen0[1]) * scale;
    mHsvTemp[2] = hsvWhen0[2] + (hsvWhen0[2] - hsvWhen0[2]) * scale;
    return Color.HSVToColor(mHsvTemp);
}
```

This function takes two hsv arguments and interpolates between them, depend on *scale* value. *scale* is in range from 0 to 1.
zero or less - color fully as first argument
one or greater - color fully as second argument
0.5f - average middle between them.

So, you can pass something like (float)getScrollY() / computeVerticalScrollRange () as third argument